# Generate Two Numbers from a Specified List of Numbers

Tags: java, random, collections

I want to generate two numbers in a specified list of numbers. I wrote this code but it does not work. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

```
public classl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] lottery = new int[2];
        int randomNum;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * (3,9,25,41,43,50,68)); // Random     number created here.
            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
                if (lottery[x] == randomNum) // Here, code checks if same random number generated before.
                {
                    randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * (3,9,25,41,43,50,68));// If random number is same, another number generated.
                    x = -1; // restart the loop
                }

            }
            lottery[i] = randomNum;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++)
            System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a comma separated list of numbers following `Math.random() *`?

Comment: In order to answer your question and address all the errors in your code, we would basically have to provide you with an introduction to the Java programming language. A task which Stack Overflow is not the place for.

Answer (score 0):

You can store these numbers in an array like this:

```
int[] arr = {12, 13, 4, 7, 9};
```

Then get a random number on **arr** array:

```
int rndNumber = new Random().nextInt(arr.length);
```

That's is some idea for you to solve your problem.

Comment: I think OP is going to need a lot more help than this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to select a given number of random elements from a collection.

If that is correct, then you are best off starting with a collection rather than an array as there are good methods in collections to help you. Here are some possible ways of doing it:

```
List<Integer> theNumbers = Arrays.asList(3, 9, 25, 41, 43, 50, 68);
Random random = new Random();

// using uniqueness of sets
Set<Integer> results = new HashSet<>();
while (results.size() < 2)
    results.add(theNumbers.get(random.nextInt(theNumbers.size()));

// using shuffle
Collections.shuffle(theNumbers);
List<Integer> results = theNumbers.sublist(0, 2);

// using streams (Java 8)
int[] results = random.ints(0, theNumbers.size())
    .map(theNumbers::get).distinct().limit(2).toArray();
```

There are many other ways but hopefully this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

sprinter's answer is the elegant way of doing. If you have difficulty understanding it as a beginner, following example should help you understand how we achieve this

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class LotteryGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //declare specified list of numbers
        int[] lotteryBank = {3, 9, 25, 41, 43, 50, 68};
        //get lottery numbers
        int[] lottery = getLottery(lotteryBank);

        System.out.println("The two lottery numbers are : [" + lottery[0] + ", " + lottery[1] + "]");

    }

    public static int[] getLottery(int[] lotteryBank) {
        //find the total number of elements, so that random number generated is one among these
        int indexRange = lotteryBank.length;
        //create an array to hold two random numbers
        int[] lottery = new int[2];
        //create an instance of Random
        Random r = new Random();
        //create a set to hold two unique random numbers
        Set<Integer> randomSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

        //iterate till two unique random numbers are found
        while(randomSet.size() != 2) {
            //get a random index
            int randomIndex = r.nextInt(indexRange);
            //add the element at random index to the set
            randomSet.add(lotteryBank[randomIndex]);
        }

        //convert random set to random array
        int index = 0;
        for(int x : randomSet) {
            lottery[index++] = x;
        }
        return lottery;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I don't encourage using int[] to store lottery numbers. In fact, don't use primitive arrays, rather use java provided collections, which comes with lot of utility methods as pointed by sprinter. This solution is aimed just to show you the way how this can be done the way your approach is inclined towards